# Do I need to protect operations against a local variable in method scope

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization, locking, monitor

Let's say I have following method that is called as callback after completion of certain work.

```
public class MyClass
    {
        private static object _synblock = new object();

    public void MyCallBackMethod()
    {
        Dictionary<int, int> myDict = new Dictionary<int, int>();

        lock(_synblock)
        {
            myDict.Add(1, 1);
        }

    }
}
```

This method could be called by multiple threads. In this scenario, do I need to synchronise any operations performed against the local variable **myDict** defined in this method scope (as I am doing above)? Or is it completely unnecessary?

Comment: Every call will have their own instance of that object so there is no need for any synchronization

Answer (score 2):

It is completely unnecessary.  Each time `MyCallbackMethod` is called, a new `myDict` object will be instantiated.  You would only need to protect access to a `Dictionary<,>` if the same instance was used by multiple threads simultaneously

Comment: I am little confused about last part of your answer. So if MyClass is a single-ton class, then I still need to put a lock around myDict ?

Comment: No.  If the `Dictionary<,>` was a field in the class it would need to be protected if the instance of that class was used in multiple threads.  In your example it is a variable in a method, which will *always* be a unique instance

Answer (score 1):

General rule is not to protect instance-level members (and data) from concurrent access in multithreading environment. Rationale is very simple: multithreading is a separate concern.

My advice is to make a multithreaded wrapper which only knows how to synchronize access. That in turn requires to have a base class or interface which would expose features of your class.

```
public interface ISomeInterface
{
    void MyCallBackMethod();
}

public class MyClass : ISomeInterface
{
    private int Data { get; set; }
    public void MyCallBackMethod()
    {
        Dictionary<int, int> myDict = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        myDict.Add(1, 1);
        // access this.Data - this is the part that would
        // make problems in case of multithreaded access
    }
}

public class ThreadSafe : ISomeInterface
{
    private ISomeInterface Contained { get; }
    private object SyncRoot { get; } = new object();

    public ThreadSafe(ISomeInterface contained)
    {
        this.Contained = contained;
    }

    public void MyCallBackMethod()
    {
        lock (this.SyncRoot)
        {
            this.Contained.MyCallBackMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How that base class could be helpful in this case given its a variable in method scope?

Comment: I suppose that there will be other uses. With only the variable in local scope there is obviously no reason to protect from anything.

Answer (score 0):

It completely unnecessary because local variables not be shared between threads. so never have confictions